# Workbook not found when trying to call function from Excel-add in

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to call a function from a 3rd party Excel-add in a VBA-sub. The function loads data from a database into specified cells in the Excel workbook.The function I'm calling is huge and unfortunaly I can't post it in its entirety, but here are the first two lines:

```
Public Function loadFromDatabase(ByVal XLname As String, ByVal sMark As String)
Dim xlWB As Workbook
```

Then it declares a bunch of variables before running the following tests:

```
  '
  '   Get the excel book and check if it is run in compatibility mode
  '
  Set xlWB = getXLBook(XLname)
  If xlWB Is Nothing Then
  loadFromDatabase = "Workbook '" + XLname + "' not found!"
  Exit Function
  End If

  bExcel8Limits = True
  If isExcel2007orLater Then
  bExcel8Limits = bCheckCompMode(xlWB)
  End If
```

Here I get this message: "Workbook " not found!" https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Du7y.jpg .
The getXLBook function looks like this:

```
   '
   '   Routine to get a specified Workbook
   '
    Function getXLBook(sName As String) As Workbook
    Dim xlWB As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Application.Workbooks(sName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set getXLBook = xlWB
    End Function
```

A hint here may be that I'm able to call the function from a `Private Sub` place in a worksheet like this...

```
 Private Sub loadFromDB()
        Dim res As Variant
        res = Application.Run("loadFromDatabase", Me.Parent.Name, "")
        If res <> "OK" Then
            MsgBox res
        End If
 End Sub
```

...but not from a module in the same workbook like this

```
 Sub loadFromDB_test()
    Dim res As Variant
    res = Application.Run("loadFromDatabase", XLname, sMark)
    If res <> "OK" Then
        MsgBox res
    End If
 End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: To clarify, it's when running loadFromDB_test the "Workbook not found" message pops up.

**Edit 2:** An obvious hotfix (that I didnt think of) is to just call the `Private Sub` in the worksheet from the `Sub` in the module.

```
Sub load_test_new()

    Application.Run "Sheet1.loadFromDB"

End Sub
```

From a learning point of view this is clearly not a good solution as it is inefficient coding.

Comment: Try `Set xlWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(sName)`. This error happens because the workbook is not already open. If you still get an error, then check to ensure the value in `sName` is valid.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. How would you proceed to ensure the value in `sName` is valid?

Comment: In your last code block what is the value in `XLname` (or `sMark`) ? - based on the error message you posted, you're not passing in any value. Have you decalred those as global variables somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the msgbox you display, you're passing an empty string to the function `getXLBook`. (within the scope of `getXLBook` this value is stored as `sName`, but the cause of the error is *before* you call this function).

So, somewhere in your code, *before* this:

```
Set xlWB = getXLBook(XLname)
```

You should have a line like this, where the right side of the statement assigns a string representing a full, valid filepath:

```
XLName = "C:\filename.xlsx"
```

I suspect that your code does not contain this assignment statement, so that should explain the error.

Comment: You guys are surely right that the `XLname` variable is the cause here. I have now tried to assign a a string representing a full, valid filepath to `XLname`, but now it just says "Workbook 'J:\loadtest.xlsm' not found".

Comment: Did you make the change in the `getXLBook` function to `Set xlWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(sName)`?

Comment: Yes. Got the same msgbox.

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` statement in your function. This will prevent you from seeing useful alerts/error messages which should help you identify why you're not getting anything returned from the function. Perhaps the file is protected, in-use by another user, or some other property is making it unable to open without user input (e.g., prompts to update links/external data sources, etc.)

Comment: I'm not able to make permantent changes to the add-in as it is used by others. I've decided to not spend more time on this issue. Thanks for your input!